# VBA: Cut Substring and Insert to New Row or TTC+Transpose+Insert Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attemping to write a VBA module that will search through cell range A1:E400 in a Worksheet:

- find a cell where there is a ",":
- Cut the substring right of the "," from the cell
- Insert a row below the found values' row (for the first instance of this per row, so that a new row isn't inserted multiple times as it loops
- Insert the cut substring value as an offset one cell down (into the blank cell on the newly inserted row)
- Trim the comma, and loop through each cell until completed

An example of the dataset I'm working with, as well as the ideal output is included below:

[Data Set & Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwZZk.png)

My current VBA Module looks like this:

```
Sub FindDupes()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Strng As String
Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=",", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Select
Else
End If
```

This gets me as far as finding cell values with the "," value and selecting them, but I feel like I am biting off more than I can chew here. I'm not very experienced with VBA and would love some help, I understand this is likely pretty complex..

Something I have oconsidered as a potentially easier approach would be to Text-To-Columns and vertically transpose, but ideally there would be a way for the values to insert the required rows, then paste into the empty cells as required (overwriting the cells with "," in them), e.g:

```
Sub Vertical()
Dim i As Long, st As String
i = 1
Dim startP As Range
For Each r In Selection
    If i = 1 Then
        st = r.Text
        i = 2
    Else
        st = st & "," & r.Text
    End If
Next r

Set startP = Selection(1, 2)
ary = Split(st, ",")
i = 1
For Each a In ary
    startP(i, 1).Value = a
    i = i + 1
Next a End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think Text-To-Columns and vertically transpose ist the better approach. You can still insert as many rows as needed befor doing that. But: if there only is one row in the raw data, why should you do that? If you want to do, You should look for the max amount of commas in one cell per row and insert that amount of additional rows.

Comment: I like the idea of that, do you have any documentation for the insert rows based on the quantity of commas in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

something like - not tested!

```
dim max_commas as integer
dim count_commas as integer
    For Each zelle In rngRowChosen
       count_commas = Len(string)-Len(Replace(string,",",""))
       if count_commas > max_commas then max_commas = count_commas 
    Next
```

insert as many rows as max_commas (replace "4" with the row number where this should go)

either

```
row_insert_Start = 4
Rows(row_insert_Start:row_insert_Start+max_commas).Insert
```

or

```
row_insert_Start = 4
Range("A"&row_insert_Start&":A"&row_insert_Start+max_commas).EntireRow.Insert
```